# How to automatically split a pandas dataframe into multiple chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe

We have a batch processing system which we are looking to modify to use multiple threads. The process takes in a delimited file and performs calculations on it via pandas.

I would like to split up the dataframe into N chunks if the total amount of records exceeds a threshold. Each chunk should then be fed to a thread from a threadpool executor to get the calculations done, then at the end I would wait for the threads to sync and concatenate the resulting DFs into one.

Problem is that I'm not sure how to split a Pandas DF like this. Let's say there's going to be an arbitrary number of threads, 2 (as an example), and i want to start the split if the record number is over 200000

So the idea would be, if I send a file with 200001 records, thread 1 would get 100000, and thread 2 would get 100001. If I send one with 1000000, thread 1 would get 500000 and thread 2 would get 500000.

(If the total records don't exceed this threshold, I'd just execute the process on a single thread)

I have seen related solutions, but none have applied to my case.

Comment: if statements would work i would think...

Comment: Have a look at: https://dask.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I've included example code of how to split. Then, using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it will execute the code with eight threads, in my case (you can use the `Thread` library too). The `process_pandas` function is just a dummy function; you can use whatever you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as th

threshold = 300
block_size = 100
num_threads = 8

big_list = pd.read_csv('pandas_list.csv',delimiter=';',header=None)

blocks = []

if len(big_list) > threshold:
    for i in range((len(big_list)//block_size)):
        blocks.append(big_list[block_size*i:block_size*(i+1)])
    i=i+1
    if i*block_size < len(big_list):
        blocks.append(big_list[block_size*i:])
else:
    blocks.append(big_list)

def process_pandas(df):
    print('Doing calculations...')
    indexes = list(df.index.values)
    df.loc[indexes[0], 2] = 'changed'
    return df

with th(num_threads) as ex:
    results = ex.map(process_pandas,blocks)

final_dataframe = pd.concat(results, axis=0)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `df.loc[indexes[0], 2] = 'changed'`?
I'm also confused with `process_pandas` in general, it takes a df as argument, but you pass it a list of df, how is the function knowing that it needs to create a list of indexes for every df in the list?

Comment: @Dasph Hey, is just a dummy function. Keep in mind that when you slice a pandas dataframe you keep the initial indexes. For example if i'm slicing in block of 100 the first block ids will be 0 to 99, second 100 to 199, third 200 to 299 etc... thats why i need to list all index values for each data frame and locate the element to change using those indexes. In my example for every block entering my function i'm changing the first row third column (called 2). Block one: df.loc[0, 2] = 'changed' block 2: df.loc[100, 2] = 'changed' block 3: df.loc[200, 2] = 'changed' etc...

Comment: But you can use your own function with a dataframe as argument. Keep in mind that ThreadPoolExecutor maps a function to a list. Executes a function for every item on a list with a defined number of threads. In this case i'm executing the function process_pandas in every item in blocks using 8 threads. Finaly ex.map() returns a list of all the returned values for each item in the list. In that case is returning n dataframes n=len(blocks)

Answer (score 2):

```
def do_something(df):
    if len(df) > some_threshold:
       pivot = len(df)//2
       threading.Thread(target=do_something,args=(df[:pivot]).start()
       return do_something(df[:pivot])
    actually_do_something_with_smallish_df(df)
```

maybe?

Comment: doing with iloc may be more safe ~

Comment: depending on what OP is doing yeah :P